# Will $_POST array only contain what's submitted by user

Tags: php, forms, post

Can i rely on that every browser will only send the POST data from the form they were posted from, or is there some browsers that sends additional data along?

The reason i am asking is, that i have a form with a lot of fields, that may only be numeric. So the easiest validation would be to just run it through a function that checks if every field is numeric.

The browsers that i have on my machine, only sends the fields from the form, so i'm hoping that goes for every other browser.

Comment: You assume that post requests can only be made from a browser, and that users cannot tamper with the form fields within their browser.

Comment: There's always can be a smartass or blackhat dude that will try to mess up with you. Never be lazy with user's data.

Comment: Well in case they do, the validation will fail, and nothing will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i rely on that every browser will only send the POST data from the form they were posted from, or is there some browsers that sends additional data along?

No. Not at all. Browser *usually* don't send other POST data if not specific by the users, but that's not a reason to trust POST data.

> The reason i am asking is, that i have a form with a lot of fields, that may only be numeric. So the easiest validation would be to just run it through a function that checks if every field is numeric.

I wouldn't do that. You could create an array of predefined `$_POST` indexes to check and just run a foreach on that. Don't use `foreach` on POST values directly.

> The browsers that i have on my machine, only sends the fields from the form, so i'm hoping that goes for every other browser.

That is usually the case but POST requests can be made not only via submitting your forms. Therefore any POST data should be always validated and unrequested data ignored.

Comment: "Don't use foreach on POST value" why is that?

Comment: @phpNoOb, because I (user) could mess with that array however I want. Why would you?

Comment: But the validation in my example would still fail?

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen, you haven't provided any example. What are you talking about?

Comment: "The easiest validation would be to just run it through a function that checks if every field is numeric". That could easily be done with a foreach on the $_POST array. If any value in the array, was not numeric, validation would fail, and nothing bad would happen. But i'm going to accept your answer, in that it says i cannot rely on browsers not sending additional data with POST.

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen, I still wouldn't do that. I could send thousands of POST values and with your script you would go trough all of them because you run a `foreach` script on the POST array. That would slow everything down. That's just the first idea that comes to my mind. Checking only for the keys you are actually going to use in your script is way better.